# How do you split a hexadecimal number in R to equal parts and swap them?

Tags: r, hex

I'm getting data from this device in a hexadecimal format. Let's take the example as

```
value = CB0F0B00CB0F0C00CB0F0F00... #(it keeps going)
```

What I'm intending to do is to take the first 4 numbers (`CB0F`) then leave the next 4 numbers (`0B00` - I want to use them later) then take next 4 number (`CB0F`) and it keeps going on. So basically I want to create a data frame having every 4 numbers after 4 numbers. 
How do I do this in R? 
After I get `CB0F`, I need to swap them as `0FCB` too.

[image: I think the image explains better.]

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: a data frame --> 0FCB  000B
                           0FCB  000C
                           0FCB  F0F0

Comment: alright I'll give you guys a visual. This hexadecimal code is actually a table of values. So after I split and convert to decimal, I should get a table.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Just added an image for your reference.

Comment: @Pascal Check my image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you mean this,

```
value <- "CB0F0B00CB0F0C00CB0F0F00"
x <- gsub("(.{2})(.{2})", "\\2\\1", value)
substring(x, seq(1,nchar(x),4), seq(4,nchar(x),4))
# [1] "0FCB" "000B" "0FCB" "000C" "0FCB" "000F"\
```

> I was able to get [1] 4043 11 4043 12 4043 15 as output. Now I want to save it as a data frame. 4043, 4043, 4043 as one column and 11, 12, 15 as one column. How do i do that?

```
x <- c(4043 ,11, 4043 ,12, 4043 ,15)
data.frame(num1=x[seq(1, length(x), 2)], num2=x[seq(2, length(x), 2)])
#   num1 num2
# 1 4043   11
# 2 4043   12
# 3 4043   15
```